# How can I list all the get properties from a give object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reflection, getter

Give the class:

```
export class Foo
{
    #x: number;
    #y : number;

    constructor()
    {
        this.#x = 20;
        this.#y = 10;
    }

    public get a(): string { return "baa"; }
    public get n(): number { return 20; }
}
```

How can I get the getters properties  i.e., `["a", "n"]`? I have no code to show yet, I've looked [`reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) and [`reflect-metadata`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) and I couldn't find anything to list those. I'm using typescript but javascript solutions are welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the property descriptors of the prototype (or of the object and every one of its prototypes) and see if the descriptor has a `get` function.

```js
const logGetters = obj => {
  if (!obj) return;
  for (const [key, desc] of Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj))) {
    if (desc.get && key !== '__proto__') console.log(key); // exclude Object.prototype getter
  }
  logGetters(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
};

class Foo {
  #x;
  #y;
  constructor() {
    this.#x = 20;
    this.#y = 10;
  }

  get a() {
    return "baa";
  }
  get n() {
    return 20;
  }
}

const f = new Foo();
logGetters(f);
```

For Typescript, just annotate with `const logGetters = (obj: object) => {`.

Answer (score 2):

You can `filter` over `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`.

```js
class Foo
{
    #x;
    #y;

    constructor()
    {
        this.#x = 20;
        this.#y = 10;
    }

     get a()  { return "baa"; }
     get n()  { return 20; }
}
const res = Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Foo.prototype))
  .filter(([k, d])=>typeof d.get === 'function').map(([k])=>k);
console.log(res);
```